# VK API выделить в сообщении пользователя, но не оповещать его об этом

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я использую самописное API через long pool 5.85.

Мне нужно отправить сообщение со списком онлайн игроков, причем онлайн пользователи будут выделены синим цветом (При клике на них можно будет попасть на их профиль), но не оповещать их об этом.

Я пытался делать:
`[id...|Тест]` - Приходит оповещение
`[id...|Тест ]` - Все отлично на ПК, но на телефоне не отображается синим
`[vk.com/id...|Тест]` - Все отлично на телефоне, но не отображается на ПК синим

Что делать? Как реализовать задачу? Iris Чат-Менеджер умеет отправлять такого рода сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо при отправке сообщения добавить параметр `disable_mentions`.

Описание параметра с документации метода [message.send](https://dev.vk.com/ru/method/messages.send):

> **Необязательный параметр.** Информация о том, отключить ли уведомление об упоминании в сообщении. Возможные значения:
>
> - `1` — отключить уведомление об упоминании в сообщении.
> - `0` — не отключать уведомление об упоминании в сообщении.